# Знаки препинания в конструкции "описывать...(,) как"

Tags: пунктуация

"Люди, непосредственно контактировавшие с этим материалом, описывают его консистенцию(,) как аналогичную пластилину из набора для лепки «Play-Doh»."
Ставим ли мы тут запятую? По-моему, нет. Тут нет уподобления, а союз "как" может быть заменен на "в качестве". Так ли это или я не прав?

Comment: По-моему тоже нет, не вижу тут для неё основания

Comment: Да, это так, вы правы

Comment: Контактировавшие = прикасавшиеся, не испытав на деле, очевидно никак не могут описать консистенцию материала.